# set option "selected" attribute from dynamically created options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select 3 dynamic select option
on the last select option there is always 1 option only

```
<select class="wpce-field-term" id="wpce-3" data-level="3" data-required="no" data-required-message="" data-type="term">
    <option value="">PCD</option>
    <option value="15437">5x108</option>
</select>
```

but it is dynamic.

i want to always auto select the first option so i use this

```
$("#wpce-3 option:nth(1)").attr("selected", "selected");
```

but the problem is that it is dynamic and the third option is not yet available until select option 1 > select option 2 are selected

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] that demonstrates your problem. Your explanation is very much lacking in details

Comment: I'd suggest setting the selected option at the point you create the select elements, not using JS as a crutch to fix the problem

Comment: Show the dynamic part (js), and we will help you better

Comment: i can not provide a runnable example since it is dynamic select form

Comment: @SKJ all the 3 select option are dynamic but the last one always have 1 option and there i am trying to add selected to it

Comment: @jodo its the option with value "15437" ?

Comment: @SKJ yes but the value always change as well but it is always one option

Comment: Did u tryed eq() ? https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240455/discussion-between-jo-do-and-skj).